# Visual Studio 2010 Data Generation Plan requiring tables for FK reference when no tables even checked

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to make a data generation plan for a single unit test but against an enterprise sized database. First thing I wanted to do was "Exclude all tables from Data Generation"

However this has left numerous tables mandatory selected due to "Included in data generation (because of foreign key reference)"

I'm assuming there is some kind of circular constraint causing this. But I think it's interesting I can't start from ground zero and select the tables I want, totally unrelated to the the tables involved in this issue.

Ideas? I basically want the "Exclude all tables.." to actually do what it says it intends to do without tinkering with foreign keys in my isolated development environment just so I can get a 1-2 table data generation plan chugging.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible.  If you import Table A that has a fk reference to Table B, then Table B has to be imported.  Not all of Table B will be imported, just the records referenced by Table A that will be imported.

There's no way around this because of the nature of foreign key constraints unless you disable them.

Comment: I created a feature request here: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2346682-support-the-ability-to-exclude-tables-from-data-ge